# Can I differentiate between a UPS, Generator and Main sine wave using a micro-controller?

Tags: microcontroller, power, signal, sine, signal-processing

Are there any distinguishing features of a mains power supply that will allow me to tell the difference between mains power supplied by

1. the utility company,
2. a generator, or
3. a UPS?

How can I use a microcontroller to make this determination?

Comment: Do you know whether the UPS outputs square or sine wave?

Comment: @Renan ups can square/modified sine/pure sine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mains signal is generated using a generator, so you can't differentiate between those two, and about UPS (inverter), it depends, is it a sine wave inverter or a digital inverter?

If its a sine wave inverter, you can but it looks quite similar to the sine wave. If it's a digital inverter the signal is bit different from the sine wave, they look like steps going up and down.

Now back your question, to distinguish between them using a micro-controller , yes you can, but how? That is another rabbit hole, of course the signal has to be conditioned before hooking it up to the uC so it doesn't go up in smoke.

I hope this clears thing up for you.